# How to convert GeoJSON to PNG image

Tags: python, geojson, image, png

I'm looking to use the `geojson` module in Python, as well as Pilllow to convert a .geojson to a .png image. I know how to extract the data from the file but I don't know what to do from there.

Comment: Lots of questions: why Pillow? Hard dep or something else is fine? GeoJSON to image: is it points, lines, polygons? Because GeoJSON = no style just shape. Extent around your GeoJSON? if not, your points,lines, polygons within GeoJSON may be not well visible e.g on the border of the image. Projection? same data will not plot the same on your PNG

Comment: No sorry there's no restrictions on it I just need it to become a .png image in some way. I need the lines so that I can use them as roads in my project. For the projection I will be using Spherical Mercator.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  What have you tried?  What was the result?  Please [edit] your question to include some code you've tested and details of the result.

Comment: Install gdal and use `gdal.RasterizeLayer`